# View all queries and delete with a confirmation

Tags: powershell, directory, recursive-query

I have a PowerShell script that searches and displays folders with username as title from different paths in a file (The file containing the paths is called paths.ini).

Now I would like to copy and add to the PowerShell: It should display all found folders and then ask at the end whether all folders and subfolders should be deleted. Answering yes then it recursively deletes all found folders and answering no just exits without deleting.

I've made it this far (See code below):
Now all folders are deleted recursively with the user, but it doesn't ask me if I'm sure, nor does it indicate which folders are being deleted. Can someone help me? I am grateful for any help.

```
# Checking userhome folders
# =========================
$testpaths = $false
$temp = ""
foreach ($i in $data1){
    $temp = $i.path + "*$sam*\"
    if (Test-Path $temp){
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Info: " $i.description
        Write-Host " ---> " $temp
        $testpaths = $true
        Remove-Item $temp -Recurse -Force
    } # if
} # foreach
if (!$testpaths){
    Write-Host "No matching folders in path from paths.ini found" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

# ========================================================================================================================
# ========================================================================================================================
# Last tasks
# ========================================================================================================================

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "====================================================================================================" -ForegroundColor Green
CMD /C PAUSE

# ========================================================================================================================
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Remove-Item $temp -Recurse -Force
```

to

```
Remove-Item $temp -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$true
```

because

```
[-Confirm](before  deleting any file ask for confirmation)-optional
```

Comment: Thank you! But...

...isn't there the possibility that it doesn't ask for each individual folder, but only asks once?